# TrafficStats Specific application - specific network interface

Tags: android, linux, networking

I know I can use the following methods of trafficstats api to get bytes sent and received for ALL network interfaces for any given app. But how do I get stats for only mobile? So that I can seperate mobile and wifi data.

> getUidTxBytes(int uid)
>   Get the number of bytes sent through the
>   network for this UID.
>
> getUidRxBytes(int uid)
>   Get the number of bytes received through the
>   network for this UID.

Seems like something like this is missing from API. And other way to get it 
getUidMobileRxBytes(int uid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but you can only get per-interface stats for the entire device, not per UID.

You can estimate per-interface, per-UID stats by collecting both the all-interface, per-UID stats and the per-interface, whole-device stats, then assuming that the ratio of the interfaces for the whole device is approximately the ratio that would be for that individual UID. For short time spans, this is likely to be fairly accurate, as the device will only switch interfaces periodically.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.formation.traficstates;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.net.TrafficStats;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TraficstatesActivity extends Activity {

    private Handler mHandler=new Handler();;

    private long mStartRX;





    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        mStartRX=TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();

        if (mStartRX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED) {

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            alert.setTitle("Uh Oh!");

            alert.setMessage("Your device does not support traffic stat monitoring.");

            alert.show();

        } else {

            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);

        }  
    }

    private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {


        long rxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()- mStartRX;

        TextView RX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewRX);

        RX.setText("\nbytes recreived :"+Long.toString(rxBytes));


        }

        };

}
```