# get information of web request in android

Tags: android

Is it possible to obtain all the information of web requests in android without changing the program? I mean whether we can, in android, write a program and get type, time or server IP of a web request from the browser.

I am appreciated of any help.

Comment: what kind of information do you want? information about a web request your application does to a remote server?

Comment: almost, does that have security problem?

Comment: if your application makes the web request, then you are free to examine it all you want. On the other hand, if you want information about web requests from the browser, you are spying on the user.

Comment: Axarydax, thank you for your reply, I just wonder how Onavo manage to work and consider it may examine the web request from a application and access the server instead

Answer (score 0):

> I mean whether we can, in android, write a program and get type, time or server IP of a web request from the browser.

Theoretically and by documentations: NO

in Practice : Yes, (but  I wont tell how). So keep in mind this when you want some security stuff

Comment: matheszabi, thank you for your reply, I just wonder how Onavo manage to work and consider it may examine the web request from a application and access the server instead

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to measure data usage (based on reference to Onavo),
you have to query the network interfaces (pdp0,rmnet0,pdp0,eth0,bnep0,tiwlan0 etc) - see class [NetworkInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface.html), then check [TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) class for retrieving data from it.

Also look in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589372/trafficstats-specific-application-specific-network-interface), it deals with traffic stats.